# How do I create a wireless ad hoc network in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I want to directly connect my smartphone to my Windows 10 laptop through WiFi without using a router. Like using a cross-over LAN cable, but with WiFi. In previous Windows versions, you were able to configure this through the GUI, but in Windows 10, you can *only* create a mobile hotspot which is not exactly the same.

So, how can I create a wireless ad hoc network in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 10, it is still possible to create a wireless ad hoc network, but not through the GUI. You have to use an elevated CMD or PowerShell.

Before creating it, make sure your WiFi adapter supports the creation of a wireless ad hoc network. Execute the following command:

```
netsh wlan show drivers
```

Assert that the line `Hosted network supported:` ends with `Yes`. Otherwise, you have to update your drivers or use different drivers (like using a more specific driver for your adapter model instead of a generic driver).

## Creation

1. Configure your wireless ad hoc network:

   ```
   netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MySSID key=MyPassword keyUsage=temporary
   ```

   If you plan to reuse this configuration, omit the `keyUsage` parameter (or set it to `persistent`). Setting it to `temporary` makes sure that the password will not be stored permanently.
2. Enable your wireless ad hoc network:

   ```
   netsh wlan start hostednetwork
   ```

You are then ready to go. You can issue `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` to monitor its status or `ipconfig /all` to retrieve the IP address of your laptop for the wireless ad hoc network.

## Deletion

1. Disable your wireless ad hoc network:

   ```
    netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
   ```
2. Delete your wireless ad hoc network configuration. Unfortunately, you cannot do that directly. Your SSID will remain in the registry, for example. A workaround is to reset the configuration to its defaults:

   1. Stop the WLAN AutoConfig service:

      ```
       Stop-Service wlansvc
      ```
   2. Delete the wireless ad hoc network configuration from the registry:

      ```
       Remove-Item "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings"
      ```
   3. Start the WLAN AutoConfig service (it will automatically restore the defaults in the registry):

      ```
       Start-Service wlansvc
      ```

Comment: Sadly it appears the Windows 10 requirement to use WDI drivers for newer versions removes the ability for any recent WiFi driver to support ad-hoc networks.

Comment: @NetMage Maybe you can do it with a mobile hotspot then, without actually sharing an internet connection. Not tested yet...