# Creating an ad hoc wifi network without an internet connection on windows 10/11

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I need to create a local area network (without using a router) that will allow me to connect my phone to my PC over a LAN connection, even if there is no internet connection.

I know that I can create a mobile hotspot from windows 11 by going to Settings -> Network & internet -> Mobile hotspot.
(e.g. https://www.alphr.com/laptop-pc-wireless-router/)

The problem is that this doesn't work if you don't have an internet connection on the PC. It will maintain the connection if the internet cuts out, but without internet at the start the system cannot start the hotspot.
[image]

There are old instructions about using `netsh wlan` (e.g [How do I create a wireless ad hoc network in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1658424/how-do-i-create-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network-in-windows-10)) but those no longer work. (See NetMage's comment on the accepted answer:

> Sadly it appears the Windows 10 requirement to use WDI drivers for newer versions removes the ability for any recent WiFi driver to support ad-hoc networks. –
> NetMage  Feb 28 at 21:25

This doesn't feel like an unreasonable request, but it seems to be very difficult.

Comment: It is just easiest to use a router so that all devices can properly get a DHCP address from the router.

Comment: Absolutely. But we're trying to deploy a device with the fewest moving parts possible. I have to persuade my boss that it can't be done before he lets me add a router.

Comment: I cannot do this from Windows and if I use my iPhone, it does not create a LAN.

Comment: Have you checked, using `netsh wlan show driver`, if the current driver shows, "Hosted network supported", *per* https://support.structure.io/article/136-how-do-i-use-uplink-without-public-wifi-router ?  If so, it might still work... though it might be blocked by Group Policy, for **security reasons**, which gives you a talking-point to convince management that a router is needed.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it says "No". I can't find the reference now, but it was trying to turn that on that led me to believe that it's permanently disabled in win10/11 these days.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik security reasons is always a good talking point. I'll be able to use that too. Thanks.

Comment: Note that, even some Wifi APs stop wifi when internet fails, by default. This is so the phones can switch to something else such as mobile data. Otherwise the phones are locked into a strong wifi signal and there is no Internet connection available to the user.

Comment: Cost is another issue. Routers are so cheap and you can even pick up second hand ones. And possible your labour could cost more.