# Can I create a wireless ad hoc network in Windows 11?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, ipad, windows-networking

I have a program called TotalMix on my Windows 11 laptop, and an iPad app called TotalMix Remote connects to it on a specified IP address and port number.

This works when both devices are on my home wifi network, but I want to use them at other venues where there's no existing wifi network. Can't the two devices communicate directly with each other? There must be a way to set up a virtual/ad-hoc LAN using wifi or Bluetooth, right?

In Windows Settings -> Network & internet -> Mobile hotspot, I see an option to "Share my internet connection" over Wi-Fi, but it's disabled when I don't have an internet connection (and it's unclear whether this would allow communication between the laptop and connected devices). Is there some other software that can access this functionality of my wifi hardware?

Related: [How do I create a wireless ad hoc network in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1658424). A comment there: "Sadly it appears the Windows 10 requirement to use WDI drivers for newer versions removes the ability for any recent WiFi driver to support ad-hoc networks."

Does that mean this is impossible?

Comment: Don't confuse "ad hoc" in the general sense with "ad hoc" as in the specific wi-fi technology. You're asking for the former while most posts (including the answer below) are talking about the latter. Windows can still create wi-fi networks in general, but they just don't use the particular wi-fi mode that's called "ad-hoc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately
[Hosted and Ad-Hoc Networks Are Not Working on Windows 10](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023257/wireless.html),
and the same for Windows 11.

What is left is
[Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) :

> Wi-Fi Direct (formerly Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer) is a Wi-Fi standard for peer-to-peer wireless connections that allows two devices to establish a direct Wi-Fi connection without an intermediary wireless access point, router, or Internet connection. Wi-Fi Direct is single-hop communication, rather than multi-hop communication like wireless ad hoc networks.

To check if your Windows computer supports Wi-Fi Direct, run CMD as
Administrator and enter the command `ipconfig /all` to list all
Wireless LAN adapters.
If the "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" is not included,
then your PC does not support WiFi Direct connections.

I don't own an Apple device, but Wi-Fi Direct is said to exist on iOS
under the names of AirPlay and AirDrop.

Once you enable Wi-Fi Direct on iOS, you may connect it from Windows
via *Settings > Devices > Bluetooth and other devices*.
Click "Add Bluetooth or other devices" and, if everything works as it should,
you should see the iOS device.

I don't know, however, if the TotalMix application will work successfully
with a Wi-Fi Direct connection, if you manage to get it going.
There are too many variables that can go wrong on the way or be incompatible.

Comment: ""Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" is not included, then your PC does not support WiFi Direct connections" - But then you could use a 'wifi direct dongle' perhaps?